# Is sine of one degree a real? If not, how is sine continuous?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, continuity

If I understand it correctly, the impossibility of trisection of an arbitrary angle implies that sine of one degree isn't a real number, but how is it then possible for sine to be continuous, if it isn't even defined everywhere?

(I believe that I don't understand correctly the consequences of the angle trisection.)

Comment: Do you mean 'rational', 'constructible' or real ?. Because sine of one degree is very much real.

Comment: The sine of any real number is real, and the sine function *is* continuous. Are you asking for an explanation of that or for the consequences of the trisection? And how did you conclude that sin(1) isn't real?

Comment: @Shailesh in light of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection#Proof_of_impossibility (the proof says that the sine of one degree would be a root of third degree polynomial, which is not a real number).

Comment: @wvxvw Of course, we are looking at quadratic closure of rational numbers -- as constructible. All algebraic numbers are not constructible, So, Thanks.

Comment: @Shailesh ok, thanks, I see now.

Comment: $\sin(1°)\approx0.01745240643728351281941897851632$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more correct statement is that it is impossible to trisect an arbitrary angle *using a compass and straightedge following the usual rules.* It is indeed possible to trisect any angle if you use another instrument [like the tomahawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection#With_a_.22tomahawk.22) or by breaking the rules [with neusis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection). The angle $3°$ can be constructed by strict means, and you can use one of the "cheats" to get $1°$.

So the sine of one degree is indeed a real number. In fact, it can be calculated by

$$\sin 1°=\frac 1{1!}\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)-\frac 1{3!}\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)^3+\frac 1{5!}\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)^5-\frac 1{7!}\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)^7+\cdots$$

to whatever precision you like.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that you can't trisect an angle (an angle it's represented by a real number, so if the angle is $\theta$ you can trisect it with three angles of $\theta/3$)

The point is that, for an arbitrary angle, you can't construct $\theta/3$ using only straightedge and compass. Nothing more that that.

I fail to see how all this is related to the sine of $1$, anyhow

Answer (score 3):

It is a real number. Galois theory just tells us that it is not one of the numbers which can be constructed in the number system which "naturally" corresponds to the straightedge and compass construction. In particular it proves that this number system is a strict subset of the real number system.

Comment: Also thanks for pointing to Galois theory! This is something on my list of the courses I'd like to take in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The usual proof that general trisection is impossible with straight-edge and compass is based on the fact that the $20^\circ=\pi/9$ angle can't be constructed with those devices.

Since sums of constructible angles are constructible, this has the consequence that the $1^\circ=\pi/180$ angle cannot be constructed. However, this doesn't mean that $s=\sin1^\circ$ is not a real number: it is and it even is an algebraic number, because, if $c=\cos1^\circ$, from De Moivre's formula we know that
$$
(c+is)^{90}=\cos90^\circ+i\sin90^\circ=i
$$
and so, equating imaginary parts (after reducing $c^2=1-s^2$), we get that $s$ is a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients. One can even give an “explicit” form for $\sin1^\circ$:

[image]

It is copied from [Exact values for the sine of all integers](http://intmstat.com/blog/2011/06/exact-values-sin-degrees.pdf) by James T. Parent. Here $I$ denotes the imaginary unit, but the number is real because it equals its conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x)$. Similarly, $e^{-ix}=cos(x)-isin(x)$
Now, $e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=2isin(x)$. Recall that $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3|}+\cdots$. Similarly, find the expansions of $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$, and you will observe that: $$sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-+\cdots.$$

**Note:** $sin(1)$ is real because $sin(1)=1-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{5!}-+\cdots \in \mathbb{R}$.